# Can I export a Visual Studio CodeMap (.DGML file) to Visio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visio, dgml

I'm trying to get my head around a rather large solution and I find that Visual Studio's CodeMap feature to be an invaluable aid.

However I'd like to take sections of the generated Codemap and from this, generate some pretty documentation from it. Ideally it seems sensible to me that it should be possible to import the .dgml into Visio, but instead I'm manually re-created a copy of it in Visio by hand.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

If not, I might set my next project as writing a DGML to VSDX converter.

Comment: This question is mentioned [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300392/how-do-i-ask-if-a-question-was-resolved?cb=1). The question there was if you ever solved this problem.

Comment: The question **there** was if you ever solved this problem, however it was never asked **here** in an explicit manner.

Comment: In other words - mentioning that someone asks a question is not equivalent to actually asking that question.

Comment: @MichalStefanow I don't really understand your point. It is not Angelos question and quite likely he/she doesn't care about the answer so directing them to the place with the question is better than asking it here.

Comment: You need to use an [intermediate format](https://visual-integrity.com/faqs/svg-in-visio/), you can create the SVG file with [this add-in](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisLovett.DgmlPowerTools2017).  No real idea how well this works.